# why is return type `null` (or any other type) assignable to return type `void`?

Tags: typescript

As you may know, in strict mode only `undefined` is assignable to type `void`. So if you try:

```js
declare let _void: void;
_void = null; // error
_void = 5; // error
```

you'll get errors

> *[type]* is not assignable to type void.

But if you try this as a return type, everything is okay:

```js
declare let voidReturn: () => void;
declare let nullReturn: () => null;
declare let numReturn: () => number;

voidReturn = numReturn;
voidReturn = nullReturn;
```

`void` behaves here like `any` since it can accomodate any type (but it only works in one way - assigning `void` to any other return type rises an error).

Why is that? Is this a bug or a feature?

Comment: this: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void partially answers my question.

Comment: it seems that the whole concept of `void` is broken since you can't return nothing from a function. If you don't use `return` in a function, the function still returns `undefined`. This is actually adding third incarnation of nothing beside `null` and `undefined` to the language. Not smart. `void` just shouldn't be used.

Comment: `void` as a function return type doesn't mean that the function returns "nothing". It means that the function's return value should not be used by the caller.  Whether or not it is "broken" or "not smart" is primarily a matter of opinion, but it is a feature and not a bug.  Generally speaking, features like these are carefully considered by the language maintainers and inconsistencies often represent trade-offs between different use cases.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Canonical answers to this question can be found in:

- [The TypeScript FAQ entry](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void) for "Why are functions returning non-`void` assignable to function returning `void`?"
- [microsoft/TypeScript#8581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8581) "how come () => void is a subtype of () => a if void isn't a subtype of a and a isn't subtype of void?"
- [microsoft/TypeScript#20006](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/20006) "[documentation] Clarify the semantics of void"
- and many others like microsoft/TypeScript  [#8240](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8240), [#8584](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8584),  [#8615](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/8615), [#9603](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/9603), [#19014](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/19014), etc...

---

It is the intended behavior, not a bug. TypeScript's `void` type is usually supposed to represent something *unusable*, not necessarily *absent*.

On the one hand, the compiler assumes that it is probably an error for you to intentionally and explicitly assign a value of any non-`undefined` type to a *variable or property* of type `void`.

On the other hand, it treats a function whose return type of `void` to mean "callers cannot safely use the return value of this function", not "this function will definitely return `undefined`."  Therefore it lets you assign a non-`void`-returning function value anywhere a `void`-returning function is expected, since the caller would never be checking the return value anyway.

These two situations are, on the face of it, inconsistent; generally speaking, due to [covariance of return types](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covariant_return_type), the type `()=>A` is assignable to `()=>B` if and only if `A` is assignable to `B`.  This breaks down with `void`, and is presumably why you are bothered by the situation.

---

But despite being inconsistent it is, for better or worse, intentional.  The reason is that it is *incredibly useful* to be able to ignore callback return values, especially for arrow functions which happen to have side effects and return values.  The go-to example here is [`Array.prototype.push()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/push), which mutates the array you call it on and returns its new length.  I want to call

```
const arr1 = [4, 5, 6];
const arr2 = [1, 2, 3];
arr1.forEach(v => arr2.push(v))
```

without having `forEach()` get angry at me because `push()` returns a `number` instead of the `void` it was promised:

```
interface Array<T> {
    pedanticForEach(cb: (val: T) => undefined): void;
}
Array.prototype.pedanticForEach = Array.prototype.forEach;

arr1.pedanticForEach(v => arr2.push(v)); // error!
arr1.pedanticForEach(v => (arr2.push(v), undefined)); // okay
arr1.pedanticForEach(v => void arr2.push(v)); // okay
```

But the analogous operation with `void` values themselves is *much less useful*.  There is no common use case in which someone really wants to assign a `number` value explicitly to a variable of type `void`.  It's probably an error when you do it.

In order to make it consistent, they'd either have to allow this probable error, or force people to wrap their not-actually-`void` returning callback functions with something explicitly `void`-ish.  Either of which would hurt productivity.

So usefulness and developer productivity win over soundness and consistency in this case. Such trade-offs are common in the language; strict soundness and type safety is not one of TypeScript's design goals.  In fact, [TypeScript Design **Non**-Goal](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/TypeScript-Design-Goals#non-goals) #3 is to

> Apply a sound or "provably correct" type system. Instead, strike a balance between correctness and productivity.

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/MYewdgzgLgBAhgJwQRhgXhgbQCwBoYCs+AbALoDcAUKJLIggEzpbL4P4DMFl9yAdADMQCAKJxgACwAUAN3QA+eEgZ8ADgFcI0mQEodlSgEswUAKYIB40zACCSOAE8APABVFAb0oxvMVaYAmcCaGwABiwmKSUsAARgBcMLJwADYJLjoKMOpg-qYCxgE6CTIghv5UAL6UdgiOagggUI0OfmoBQVAh4aLiEsw1daoNTVAtpoIRvVQ8SPx+gcFhk1FyaIr0KhpasnrkMAD0+zDmDQgAhDMobQudSz0rmVIbapraOvjZuflghTp7hzAQABrRyXObtRbdSLaTIlMpKRgvba6P4HI7A0GUIA)

Comment: Will you agree that instead of introducing `void` to the language, a better idea would be to let `undefined` be a little inconsistent in the same way `void` is? So if I have a variable of  type that returns `undefined`, I can assign to it a function that returns any other type: `let f: () => undefined = () => whateverValue`. Returning just `undefined` is a good enough indicator that you don't want the return value to be used, since `undefined` is, by its nature, useless. If adding `null` to the language was a billion dollar mistake, adding `void` is also a mistake IMHO.

Comment: Well, `undefined` has uses; you specifically do need to check values to see if they are or are not `undefined` before you use them (with `--strictNullChecks`), whereas you should not be doing anything with a value of type `void`, not even checking it for equality. `[1,2,3].find(callback)` returns  `number | undefined`, and if I could substitute anything for its result you would have a problem.

Comment: My opinions about `undefined`-vs-`void`, or whether a particular design choice in the language is a "mistake" or could have been done better, while **obviously correct** , are not generally on-topic for SO. There have been many situations in which I disagree with the choices made by the language designers, but generally speaking they made those choices for reasons (which are sometimes discoverable in GitHub issues) having to do with supporting use cases that I care about less than they do. I spent a while wanting TS to be completely sound before turning to the dark side.

Comment: returning `number | undefined` is actually equal to returning `number | void` - `void` changes here its meaning from *anything* to just `undefined`. This is an example of a function that *may* return something useful (a `number`) or not. Nullish values are only meaningful in the context of other values. If a function returns just `void` or just `undefined` or just `null` there's no information there. You don't have to check or use them because you already know what's there.