# Why does TypeScript not report a "wrong" function return type

Tags: typescript

I'm surprised why TypeScript 4.4.3 would not report an invalid type for the callback function?
This seems reasonable when returning a "non-promise" type but when returning a Promise it seems likely that we must wait for it to resolve.
`setCallback` expects a function returning `void` but is invoked with a function returning `Promise<void>` indicates that there is something to wait for.

```
const setCallback = (cb: () => void): void => {
    cb();
};

const callback = (): Promise<void> => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(), 100);
    });
}

setCallback(callback);
```

[TS Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=12&ssc=1&pln=1&pc=1#code/MYewdgzgLgBBCmUDCBDANmgRi4BrGAvDABTCYBcJAlIQHwwBuIAlgCZWVNt0wDeAsACgYImGWJUA3EIC%200wUNCRYwdFhz4iEygAUATiAC2zBAB4uregXoDhovYgCuesDDDwA7jH1GT8Yg4QIGgM8Dy2opFwiAAqzIbwII5QxBI8gcGhEgA0MACMAAwFUkKRMiWCMkJCCMhq2Hik9RoVQA)

Comment: Since the return value isn't even used in any way, it doesn't matter... See [TypeScript FAQ](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/wiki/FAQ#why-are-functions-returning-non-void-assignable-to-function-returning-void)

Comment: yeah you can return anything in `callback` function

Comment: You can assign function with any return type to a void return type function, since you don't/can't use the return anyway

Comment: Does this answer your question? [why is return type \`null\` (or any other type) assignable to return type \`void\`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65721318/why-is-return-type-null-or-any-other-type-assignable-to-return-type-void)

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-files/do-s-and-don-ts.html#return-types-of-callbacks

Comment: I edited my question to make it clear, that I specifically care about the fact that the callback function does return a Promise and this indicates that we "should" wait for the promise to resolve.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## TypeScript doesn't care

You only give a *function reference* to `setCallback()` which can be anything you like. As long as you don't invoke the function itself, it counts as an `object` and **TypeScript won't give you a TypeError** since your **function is expecting an `object`**.

If you were to call the `object`, it would turn into it's respective type for which TypeScript does give you a TypeError in case of a mismatch.

1. **Variables passed by reference**

> In Pass by Reference, a function is called by directly passing the reference/address of the variable as the argument. Changing the argument inside the function affects the variable passed from outside the function. In Javascript objects and arrays are passed by reference.

2. **Functions (MDN)**

> Generally speaking, a function is a "subprogram" that can be called by code external (or internal in the case of recursion) to the function. Like the program itself, a function is composed of a sequence of statements called the function body. Values can be passed to a function, and the function will return a value.

> In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are Function objects.

## Example 1

Since I cannot use `.then()` on void functions, I had to create an [IIFE](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/IIFE) to make it `async` and it still works even though I'm expecting a void type callback.

```
const setCallback = (cb: () => void): void => {
    (async () => await cb())().then(() => console.log("Hi"));
};

const callback = (): Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(0), 100);
    });
}

setCallback(callback);
```

## Example 2

If you try to invoke it with a `Promise` return type:

> Argument of type 'Promise' is not assignable to parameter of type '() => void'.
> Type 'Promise' provides no match for the signature '(): void'.

The error refers to the mismatch of [Function signatures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Signature/Function).

```
const setCallback = (cb: () => void): void => {
    (async () => await cb())().then(() => console.log("Hi"));
};

const callback = (): Promise<number> => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(() => resolve(0), 100);
    });
}

setCallback(callback());
```