# Is @typescript-eslint/no-invalid-void-type universally applicable?

Tags: typescript, static-analysis

I'm looking at enabling the lint rule `@typescript-eslint/no-invalid-void-type`. I want to make sure everything it's flagging is truly something I always want to get rid of. Just to check my understanding. Are the following statements correct?

1. There's never any reason to include `void` in a type union, like `string | void`.
2. There's never any reason to declare a function that takes `void` as a param. (Except for something like `this: void`).
3. There's never any reason to put `void` in a container generic, like `Array<void | string>`.
4. Putting `void | undefined` on a function return signature (e.g. `() => void | undefined`) is redundant.
5. If you have `() => SomeType | void`, you should use `() => SomeType | undefined` instead.

And the reason for most of those statements being true is that you can't instantiate a value of type void, so something like Array<string | void> makes no sense. Right?

Comment: Seems like you're going to get lots of opinion here; what would an authoritative answer look like?

Comment: I'm sure you know it, but `this: void` is not "taking a param", it's an ugly (debatable) choice of syntax

Comment: I don't think this is opinion-based. For example, "will adding `void` to a type union ever change what the type union evaluates to?" is an objective question.

Comment: One caveat to #2 is that [ms/TS#27522](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/27522) implemented so that trailing `void` parameters are considered optional, but this behavior has all kinds of weird quirks.  See [this](https://tsplay.dev/N7PBRm).

Comment: "will adding void to a type union ever change what the type union evaluates to?" is an objective question I don't see in the plaintext of the question itself.  What I see in the question is a set of fairly broad statements, most of which depend on whether there is "any reason" to do something.  Could you rephrase to a form which doesn't encourage opinion?  Your 4th and 5th statements seem a little less opinion-ish. Does [this](https://tsplay.dev/NrK61m) indicate that statement 4 is false?

Comment: Like, if I step back and look at your question while squinting, I'd say that using `void` anywhere except for a return type is often a bad idea, because `void` is wacky and has a few inconsistent uses that play not-so-nicely together.  See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69732504/2887218) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65721318/2887218).  But that's my opinion.  I'm wondering how best to sum this up in a form that isn't just "jcalz's guide to writing TypeScript".