# Why do assignment statements pass type checking, but declaration statements don't?

Tags: typescript

[Typescript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABFApgZygCgJQC4BucMAJgN4BQiViATilCDUgAo1wC2MaKAdHWnAA2%20FDnIBfcuQgIMydFABMuRDkQBeAHyJCJDauwbtrDl178hInAG5yQA)

```
function test1():void{
    return Promise.resolve() // Error: Type 'Promise<void>' is not assignable to type 'void'
}

const test2: () => void = () => Promise.resolve(); // ok
```

Comment: I'm not a Typescript developer, but wouldn't this work if you just remove the `return` keyword? Basically in the second version you're just executing `Promise.resolve()` but the compiler knows you're not trying to return anything, given that it's a void function.

Comment: It's an intentional inconsistency with `void`.  You've discovered that `() => Promise<void>` is assignable to `() => void` even though `Promise<void>` is not assignable to `void`.  The answer to [the linked question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65721318/2887218) explains why it's like this.